# I am having trouble replacing a frist instance of certain word with regex_replace

Tags: c++

I am working on regular expression. I am a beginner and I need some help to figure this out.

Basically, I am looking for a pattern that solves problem of both `line0` and `line1` - I want to replace only the first occurrence of the string.

So, far I got the below code.  I have also attached an image of my output.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string line0, line1;
    line0 = "something, ford, chevy, dodge, something, honda";
    line1 = "toyota, something, ford, chevy, dodge, honda, something";
    regex pattern("^something");
    string newLine2 = regex_replace(line0, pattern, "nissan");
    cout<<newLine2<<endl;
    string newLine3 = regex_replace(line1, pattern, "nissan");
    cout<<newLine3<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: a1234910, I've cleaned up the question and adjusted it based on your comments. Please check that the description is still accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex `"^something"` means "something" at the *start* of the string (that's what the `^` anchor means), and that's why it's not working in `line1`.

If you want to replace it *anywhere* in the string, change the pattern to `"something"` (without the anchor). Just keep in mind that this will replace *all* instances and will also replace instance *within* words. For example, if you replaced `one` with `two`, you could end up with such memorable phrases as:

> When there are two, it's a foregtwo conclusion - they'll never be altwo.

To just do the word on its own, you can use word boundaries, such as with `"\\bsomething\\b"`

In addition, to relace only the *first* occurrence, there are [flags](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_replace/) to control these things. In this case, the first-only flag can be used:

```
string newLine3 = regex_replace(line1, pattern, "nissan",
    std::regex_constants::format_first_only);
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion but I need only the first instance of "something" to get replaced at a time. I just need last instance for study purpose.

Comment: @a1234910, that's done by adding a flag to the replace call, see the update.

Answer (score -1):

Your regex is anchored to the beginning of the line. You need to do:

```
regex pattern("something");
```

to replace an occurrence of the pattern anywhere in the string.

This will replace all occurrence of the pattern.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/BWZFyy).

Comment: sorry for the confusion but I need only the first instance of "something" to get replaced at a time. I just need last instance for study purpose.

Comment: Please clarify this requirement in the question. Give a sample input output that you want.